# Does not show RAW XML data

Tags: java, android, xml

I am learning from Video Tutorials and I've done exactly the same stuff that is on Video, the only difference is on the video they are doing it on Eclipse and I'm doing it on Android Studio (and I guess it should not affect  the outcome). Anyway, what I am trying to do is to get raw XML data from Apple RSS to my Android app and display it on a text field...

I have already added :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

to Manifest file

XML CODE:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView android:text="@string/hello_world" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView1" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Main Activity Code:

```
package com.example.haziqsheikhlocal.top10appsofios;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    TextView text;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        text =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        new DownloadData().execute("http://ax.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStoreServices.woa/ws/RSS/topfreeapplications/limit=10/xml");
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private class DownloadData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

        String myXmlData; // This String Will Contain Our XML Data
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) { // It Finds The First Url In BackGround;
            try{
                myXmlData = downloadXML(urls[0]); // It Downloads the first element in array Element;
            }
            catch (IOException e){
               e.printStackTrace();
                return "" ;
            }
            return null;
        }
        protected void onPostExecution(String result){
            Log.d("OnPostExecute", myXmlData);
            text.setText(myXmlData);
        }

        private String downloadXML (String theUrl) throws IOException {
            int BUFFER_SIZE = 2000;   // Buffer Size Constant
            InputStream is = null; // Declaring Input Stream
            String xmlContent = ""; // Creating empty xmlContent variable to store xml data from the web in furutre
            try {
                URL url = new URL(theUrl);
                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); // Open The Connection with url given
                conn.setReadTimeout(10000);// Read time Out 10seconds
                conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);// connection timeout 15 s
                conn.setRequestMethod("GET"); // Set the method for the URL request, one of: GET POST HEAD OPTIONS PUT DELETE TRACE are legal, subject to protocol restrictions.
                conn.setDoInput(true);
                int response = conn.getResponseCode();
                Log.d("DownloadXML", "The Ressponse Code Is: " + response);
                is = conn.getInputStream();
                InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
                int charRead;
                char[] inputBuffer = new char[BUFFER_SIZE];
                try {
                    while ((charRead = isr.read(inputBuffer)) > 0){
                        String readString = String.copyValueOf(inputBuffer, 0 , charRead);
                        xmlContent += readString;
                        inputBuffer = new char[BUFFER_SIZE];
                    }
                    return xmlContent;
                }

                catch (IOException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return null;
                }

            }finally {
                if(is != null) {
                    is.close();
                }
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Device LogCat shows no Error & showing the response code 200.
 Device LogCat:

```
03-25 22:53:09.237    1144-1144/com.example.haziqsheikhlocal.top10appsofios I/art﹕ Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
03-25 22:53:12.688    1144-1162/com.example.haziqsheikhlocal.top10appsofios D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Render dirty regions requested: true
03-25 22:53:12.718    1144-1144/com.example.haziqsheikhlocal.top10appsofios D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xa7b419c0, tid 1144
03-25 22:53:12.771    1144-1144/com.example.haziqsheikhlocal.top10appsofios D/Atlas﹕ Validating map...
03-25 22:53:13.058    1144-1162/com.example.haziqsheikhlocal.top10appsofios D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xa7b41bf0, tid 1162
03-25 22:53:13.122    1144-1162/com.example.haziqsheikhlocal.top10appsofios I/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Initialized EGL, version 1.4
03-25 22:53:13.194    1144-1162/com.example.haziqsheikhlocal.top10appsofios D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
03-25 22:53:13.256    1144-1162/com.example.haziqsheikhlocal.top10appsofios W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
03-25 22:53:13.256    1144-1162/com.example.haziqsheikhlocal.top10appsofios W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa7b3ba40, error=EGL_SUCCESS
03-25 22:53:14.100    1144-1156/com.example.haziqsheikhlocal.top10appsofios I/art﹕ Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 3424(291KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 14% free, 968KB/1135KB, paused 1.420ms total 737.728ms
03-25 22:53:15.313    1144-1161/com.example.haziqsheikhlocal.top10appsofios D/DownloadXML﹕ The Ressponse Code Is: 200
```

ADB LogCat shows this Error:

```
DeviceMonitor: Adb connection Error:An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
ddms: null
java.nio.BufferOverflowException
    at java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.put(HeapByteBuffer.java:206)
    at com.android.ddmlib.JdwpPacket.movePacket(JdwpPacket.java:235)
    at com.android.ddmlib.Debugger.sendAndConsume(Debugger.java:347)
    at com.android.ddmlib.Client.forwardPacketToDebugger(Client.java:698)
    at com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.processClientActivity(MonitorThread.java:344)
    at com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.run(MonitorThread.java:263)

ddms: Client data packet exceeded maximum buffer size [Client pid: 1272]
DeviceMonitor: Adb rejected connection to client '1537': closed
DeviceMonitor: Adb connection Error:An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
DeviceMonitor: Connection attempts: 1
DeviceMonitor: Connection attempts: 2
DeviceMonitor: Connection attempts: 3
DeviceMonitor: Connection attempts: 4
PropertyFetcher: AdbCommandRejectedException getting properties for device emulator-5554: device offline
PropertyFetcher: AdbCommandRejectedException getting properties for device emulator-5554: device offline
PropertyFetcher: AdbCommandRejectedException getting properties for device emulator-5554: device offline
PropertyFetcher: AdbCommandRejectedException getting properties for device emulator-5554: device offline
PropertyFetcher: AdbCommandRejectedException getting properties for device emulator-5554: device offline
PropertyFetcher: AdbCommandRejectedException getting properties for device emulator-5554: device offline
PropertyFetcher: AdbCommandRejectedException getting properties for device emulator-5554: device offline
PropertyFetcher: AdbCommandRejectedException getting properties for device emulator-5554: device offline
```

What I did to solve this is I went to terminal and used  `adb kill-server` and then `adb start-server`.   I ran the emulator again but still no luck ! 
Help me please .

Note: Same is happening when I am using gennymotion and I am able to use emulators browser and surf website on it..

Comment: Hi,Haziq. I cannot recreate your error. I've created new project with your source and it works. Probably your problem with config files or android sdk packages.
Please look at my source and compare your configs with mine.
[link](https://github.com/toqsan/stackoverflow_questions_29263216) 
And if problem with your SDK packages check this page
[link](http://techlovejump.com/how-to-solve-unable-to-execute-dex-java-nio-bufferoverflowexception-check-the-eclipse-log-for-stack-trace/) 
And you have little typo, you should override onPostExecute not onPostExecution